# how we can change all values inside array without looping in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that has values in some indexes now what i want to do is to change all values inside array to specific value for example 0, so how can i do that without looping i used bellow code but has syntax error, i don't know what is the syntax error here.

```
$my_array = array(
       'cen12' => 0,
       'cen67' => 1,
       'cen44' => 5
       );
$out_pot = array_map(function ($val){return 0;},$my_array);
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The code above works well and returns

```
array(3) { ["cen12"]=> int(0) ["cen67"]=> int(0) ["cen44"]=> int(0) }
```

Comment: But when i wrote that statement editor shows syntax error in function ($val) i don't know why?

Comment: Which editor?
Have you tried running your code on your server?